# Why is the Power Method giving me one of the smaller eigenvalues instead of the dominant one?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, approximation, numerical-linear-algebra

I was looking at/working on something and had a bit of a confusion about the power method. When getting the eigenvector/eigenvalue by multiplying a matrix $A$ with a vector $b_0$, are you always only supposed to get the dominant eigenvalue's eigenvector? I used two different initial $b_0$'s, which had the same entries except for one which was the opposite sign, and got 2 of the eigenvectors for the matrix, both associated with two different eigenvalues of the original matrix. One was the largest absolute eigenvalue while the other one was the largest positive eigenvalue.

I guess I mostly want to ask, wasn't the power method only supposed to give you the dominant eigenvalue? Is there any reason why I'm instead getting 2 of the eigenvectors/eigenvalues instead if I use two similar initial $b_0$'s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your second choice of $b_0$ was perpendicular to the eigenspace of the dominant eigenvalue.

For example, let
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}3 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}.$$
Then, see that for any $\varepsilon>0$ we can define
$$u=\begin{pmatrix}\varepsilon  \\ 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$$
and
$$v=\begin{pmatrix}0  \\ 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}.$$

$u$ and $v$ are as close as we like, but
$$A^n u = \begin{pmatrix}\varepsilon 3^n  \\ 2^n \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$$
and
$$A^n v = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 2^n \\ 0\end{pmatrix}.$$

For large $n$, this coordinate $\varepsilon 3^n$ will dominate, but it  vanished in $v$.

Comment: Ohh okay. I did not know this was a thing, but okay, this is interesting. Is there any reason as to why using a perpendicular vector doesn't give a proper answer with the power method (not just by checking by calculations, but generally).

Comment: @Applesauce44 Suppose you're dealing with a matrix A that can be diagonalized. Then you could write your initial vector as a linear combination of eigenvectors, $x=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i v_i$. And if $x$ is perpendicular to $v_j$, e.g., it means that $a_j=0$.

Then
$$Ax = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i Av_i = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \lambda_i v_i,$$
and, as $a_j$ is 0, $\lambda_j$ doesn't have any effect on $Ax$.

Comment: OHH yeah okay I see I see. Thank you! This is helpful!